# PHP Generated site not displaying as expected

Tags: php, html

I have a site that is generated with php.  No database or anything, but it does use Bootstrap 4.  At this point, there are only two pages.  Home and About.

http://testing.jcoulter.me

Home work exactly as expected.  Here is the about page (FYI, the about page only has the navbar and jumbotron ... there is no other content on this page).

[testing.jcoulter.me/index.php/?view=pages/about](http://testing.jcoulter.me/index.php/?view=pages/about)

As you can see, the css isn't rendering.  If you view source, everything is there.  In fact, I copied and pasted the source to a test file.

[testing.jcoulter.me/test.php](http://testing.jcoulter.me/test.php)

It displays perfectly.  The code in the test file is identical to the php generated about page.  Hence my issue.

Here is my index.php file:

```
<?php

require_once 'includes/framework.php';
require 'views/templates/header.php';
require buildView();
require 'views/templates/footer.php';
```

That's the entire index.php file. framework only has two require_once statements ... one for configuration info and the other for the buildView function.  Header has the CSS and the navbar.  Footer is, well, the footer.  The buildView function does one thing and one thing only.  It takes the view passed in the url and converts it to the proper path.  If no view is passed, it defaults to the home page.  So view=pages/about is returned by buildView as views/pages/about.php.  It works, since the about page is showing.

Any ideas why the page is not displaying as it should?  Hopefully I'm explaining this well enough.  My next step is to find a bigger hammer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A couple of things I noticed:

1. Open up your devtools on the broken test page. You will see a syntax error which is not found on your working page. Fix that, as that seems to be where you are loading your CSS from.
2. There is a ton of HTML in main.js. Is that deliberate? http://testing.jcoulter.me/index.php/includes/js/main.js

Comment: The JS should be empty.  There is no JS at this point.  I removed it, which remove the syntax error, but didn't fix the issue.  However, I think I know what the problem is, but not sure how to resolve.  The JS and CSS are being passed as index.php/includes/..... which is incorrect.  What is showing up in both is the entire home page and not the actual CSS.  What I don't know is how/why it is happening.  Brain is fried for the night.  Will look at it more tomorrow evening.  THANKS for pointing it out!!

Comment: FIXED ... until I can find a better solution. I had "includes/css/style.css" in my header.php file and it was picking up "index.php/incudes/css/style.css" for some reason.  I hard coded the domain in the stylesheet href and it now works as expected.  I'm sure there is a better way but too tired to work on it.  Thanks for pointing out the JS issue.  That wasn't the problem but it got me looking in the right direction.

Comment: Excellent. Happy to have helped.